# Easiest way to find continuous duplicate values and their position in JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check array to see if there are any continuous duplicates numbers in array and also find their position.

Example Whats exactly needed will clear your idea

```
var myCars=[1 ,1 , 2, 3, 5];   O/P:- 1 is repeated at position 0 & 1.

var myCars=[1 ,1 , 2, 5, 5];   O/P:- 5 is repeated at position 3 & 4. Since 5 is maximum number.

var myCars=[5 ,4 , 1, 1, 1];   O/P:- 1 is repeated at position 2 ,3 & 4.

var myCars=[5 ,5 , 1, 1, 1];   O/P:- 1 is repeated at position 2 ,3 & 4. Since 1 is repeated more number of times.
```

I tried doing this in number of ways but could not find the best way.
What's the easiest way to do this?

Following code I have tried but its not giving exact desired output.

```
var myarray = ["John", "Doe", "Smith", "Doe", "Joe"];

var map = {};
var count = myarray.map(function(val) {
    return map[val] = (typeof map[val] === "undefined") ? 1 : map[val] + 1;
});

var newArray = myarray.map(function(val, index) {
    return val + (map[val] != 1 ? ' - ' + count[index] : '');
});

alert(newArray);
```

Assume only elements are in array

http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Z4dgr/

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your exapmle, the 4th example, is it correct?

Comment: I'm Sorry I have just corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works exactly as it is desired

http://jsfiddle.net/9mQ2b/11/

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<script>
var myarray = ["1", "1", "4", "4", "3"];
var results = {};
var positions = {};
var j = count = -1;
for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
{ 
if (myarray[i] == myarray[i+1])  // check if num are equal
{
if (count != myarray[i])   //check if continuous num are not equal & set starting position..
{ j++; results[j] = myarray[i]; positions[j] = i; count = myarray[i];
}
if (i == 3) //  set last position of last number if last digit 
positions[j+1] = i+1;
}
else
{
if (count == myarray[i])  // set last position of digit
positions[++j] = i;
count = -1;
}
}
alert(JSON.stringify(results));
alert(JSON.stringify(positions));    
</script>
<body> 
</body> 
</html>​
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:  iterate through and check the current against the next and previous item.  Add the count of matches for each item, and the indices of the matches, to separate objects.

```
var results = {};
var positions = {};

myarray.forEach(function(item, index) { 

    if ((index > 0 && myarray[index-1] == item) || (index < myarray.length+1 && myarray[index+1] == item)) {
        results[item] = (results[item] || 0) + 1;
        (positions[item] || (positions[item] = [])).push(index);
    }
});

alert(JSON.stringify(results));
alert(JSON.stringify(positions));​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mQ2b/2/)

Comment: Can you please give working example in fiddle, its not what is desired.

Comment: @ameyarote see my update, and the Fiddle - I think that's closer to what you want.

Comment: @dbaseman- is there any alternative to access JSON.stringify(results)

Comment: @dbaseman- it does not work with this combination [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a 2 dimensional array for counting. The first simension will be the item being counted, the second simension will be the count for that item. And then do your comparison. after filling your array.

I chose this solution cause I like simple, easy-to-understand approach to programmming. Makes life easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery inArray` function for this:
Code is

```
var myarray = ["John", "John", "John", "Doe", "Doe", "Smith",
               "John", "Doe", "Joe"];


var str='';var i=0;
$.each(myarray,function()
       {
           str+=myarray[i]+'='+$.inArray(myarray[i],myarray,i)+', ';
           i++;
       })

alert(str);
```

or test the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Z4dgr/2/